# Node JS push server send/receive

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to set up a node js server to do push notifications to my browser app. I have a basic example working, but I am wondering how to send data up to the server from the client on handshake.

I Need to send to the server something like a user id, so when a notification comes in for them, it can be routed back to the user.

my server looks something like this

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8000);

function handler ( req, res ) {
    res.writeHead( 200 );
    res.end('node working');
};

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {

  socket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , "blah" );
});
```

and my client looks something like this

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

  socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    //prints data here
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In socket.io, the emit is essentially like any other event handler (e.g. jQuery's `.on('click'...)`); you declare the event and send the data. On the server, you add the `.on('event', ...)` to catch the request and process it.

The socket.io front page shows this example for the server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And this for the client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

It sounds like the part you're looking for is the `socket.emit` portion.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this sort of thing in the past by setting a cookie on the client (which you're probably doing anyway), and then using socket.io's `authorization` event. You can use this event to decide whether to even accept the socket connection to the user in the first place.

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {

    var cookie = handshakeData.headers.cookie;

    // parse the cookie to get user data...

    // second argument to the callback decides whether to authorize the client
    callback(null, true);
  });
});
```

See more documentation here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Note that `handshakeData.headers.cookie` is just a string literal representation of the cookie, so you'll have to do your own parsing.

Comment: Thanks, although the other answer by Kato is exactly what I was looking for, this will prove to be very helpful as well.