# Get SESSIONID in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, sessionid

Now, after some hours of playing around with nodejs and socket.io, I'm getting a couple more problems - one being, that I need to get the sessionID inside node.js, whitout using `app.get('/' ...` - since that event doesnt seem to fire when `socket.io` connects, it only fires `.on('connection', function( ...`

```
var express = require('express')()
express.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080)

var server = require('http').createServer(express)
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(express.get('port'))

// this event is fired, get('/', ... isnt!
server.on('connection', function(stream) {
    // ??
} )
```

The Session is initially created by the PHP application, as the user logs in. Session data is stored in the database, and the key I need to access that data is the SESSION ID. What's the easiest way to get to it? Like mentioned, I found a couple examples that used `app.get('/' ...` but I couldnt get that event to fire at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the session data is being stored as a cookie (most likely), then you should be able to re-parse that data during the socket handshake. I posted code for that on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893116/2210128), but copied the code here as well:

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {

    var cookie = handshakeData.headers.cookie;

    // parse the cookie to get user data...

    // second argument to the callback decides whether to authorize the client
    callback(null, true);
  });
});
```

If the session data is being propagated in the URL, then you may be able to gather this information from `handshakeData.url` or `handshakeData.query`. You'll probably have to do your own experimentation.

Comment: Hm, I get the header information (cookie is null) - but I dont seem to get the `Set-Cookie` data, it apparently just doesnt exist. If I check my Answer-Header with firebug, it tells me something like `Set-Cookie PHPSESSID=...; path=/` etc - but that information seems to be missing inside the handshakeData. Shouldnt it have the same headers? Maybe I'm just getting the whole SESSION concept wrong

Comment: Ah! I found the solution. Your idea seems to work, the problem I apparenly have is PHP based (by changing session.cookie_domain, it seems to deliver the PHPSESSID now) thanks a lot!